# Why can the certificate not be found by the Ingress Controller, while the certificate has been issued?

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

kubectl logs nginx-ingress-controller-X -n nginx-ingress

```
W1222 06:52:04.575115       8 controller.go:1058] Error getting SSL
certificate "app/app-tls": local SSL certificate app/app-tls was not
found. Using default certificate
W1222 06:52:09.955475       8 backend_ssl.go:48] Error obtaining X.509
certificate: no object matching key "app/app-tls" in local store
```

kubectl describe certificates nexus-tls -n cert-manager

```
Message:               Certificate issued successfully
Reason:                CertIssued
```

**Discussion**

It is unclear to me where to deploy the certmanager. I have deployed in a separate namespace, the cert has been created successfully, but the certificate cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/482#issuecomment-449664935

> Once I followed this
>   https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/blob/master/docs/tutorials/quick-start/index.rst#step-6---configure-lets-encrypt-issuer
>   and deployed the issuers in the namespace of the app, it works

Comment: The quoted link 404s...

Comment: https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/